# YUI 2.x Components Management

Tags: javascript, yui, extjs3

Hy guys.  I'm currently involved in a project using YAHOO User Interface 2.9 which I haven't used before(I have a strong background in EXTJS though). 
   Has YUI any equivalent class for Components management like the Ext.ComponentMgr in Ext 3.x?
   Ext.getCmp() was a pretty powerfull method available there, for instance one could have write:

```
var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
id: 'test_panel',
title: 'Test Panel',
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
width: 200, 
height: 130,
html : '<div>Hello World</div>'
});
```

...somewhere in the script, after myPanel was created, maybe in an AJAX callback:

```
Ext.GetCmp('test_panel');
```

Has YUI something like that or have they another method of handling objects in a unified way across the library which I'm not aware?

Answer (score 0):

In YUI 3, the equivalent is gallery-instancemanager:  http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/instancemanager  (It even supports lazy construction.)

Back-porting this to YUI 2 should be really easy.